# InDesign: Link back from cross-reference

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, cross-reference

for my recent project I have to make a PDF with endnotes at the end of every chapter. As we all know there's no easy way to do that in InDesign, only [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/indesigndocs/2009/03/endnotes_in_indesign_cs4.html) more or less official workaround and some Skripts (e.g. from [Peter Kahrel](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/foot_to_endnote.html)).

Anyway, I'm using the workaround from the Adobe-site and I'm looking for a way to *link back* to the place where the endnote has been set by clicking on the endnote.

Thanks in advance for trying to help me with this.

EDIT: I'm working with InDesign CS6.

---

**Solution:** Yes, I finally managed to come up with a solution and it's so simple that I'm embarrassed I didn't come up with it in the first place – Text Anchors and Hyperlinks.
 Needless to say that this solution is also very impractical so I hope Adobe will work on that and include endnotes.

Here's how I did it:

1. **create hyperlink destination**
   Highlight your destination text **»** Hyperlinks panel menu **»** New Hyperlink Destination… **»** Type: Text Anchor; Name: [to find it later you can leave the suggested highlighted text; I chose names like "02_03" – chapter 2; endnote 3]
   *If you're sure that your text won't change you can also set a page-anchor instead of a text anchor.*
2. **create hyperlink**
   Highlight the part you want as a hyperlink **»** Hyperlinks panel menu **»** New Hyperlink… **»** Link to: Text Anchor; Document: obviously the document with your destination; Text Anchor: the name of the Text Anchor you just created; apply Character Style to make the link visible

Don't forget to export as an interactive PDF instead of a print PDF!

Answer (score 1):

Again it's a bit of a workaround, but you might be able to use **Bookmarks** to link the endnotes back to original text. More info here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/bookmarks.html

Comment: Thanks, that's another option. But the problem is that you can't use bookmarks for the book itself, like in my project..